# Is it possible to use Javascript library in Vert.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vert.x

To develop an algorithm I used `TurfJs` library to avoid to do some calculations my self, and I have been asked to integrate the algorithm to an `Eclipse Vert.x` server, in which I'm new.

So I tried to import it directly like usual: `var turf = require("@turf/turf");`

and when I execute using this command: `./node_modules/.bin/vertx run server.js`, I get this error:

```
    Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 2762 ms, time limit is 2000
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot redefine property "name" of function IndexOutOfBoundsException (message) {
    Error.call(this);
    this.message = message || '';
  } in node_modules/@turf/turf/turf.js at line number 26251
```

Here is server.js code if needed:

```
var Router = require("vertx-web-js/router");
var turf = require("@turf/turf");


var server = vertx.createHttpServer();

var router = Router.router(vertx);

router.get("/").handler(function (ctx) {
  var response = ctx.response();

  response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

  response.end("[\"foo\",\"bar\"]");
});

server.requestHandler(router.accept).listen(8080);
```

Note: here I haven't yet used turf, because just importing it causes the above problem.

Please help, Is it possible to use Javascript/nodejs library in Vert.x ?

Comment: I tried to use `uniq` library and it haven't caused a problem, so I think the problem is with `turfjs`

Answer (score 0):

So I'm answering my question, after a lot of searches I ended that the problem is with `TurfJs` which is deprecated from `turf` to `@turf/turf` according to this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf)

so I tried to to use `turf` rather than `@turf/turf`, and it works even it show this message:

```
Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 2627 ms, time limit is 2000
Succeeded in deploying verticle
```